# when using read_csv I am getting sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas. I have downloaded adult dataset and converted it into csv file now I am trying to read the csv file using read_csv function but i am getting the following error:

```
 sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

heres the line from my code where the error is occuring-

```
    adult_df = pd.read_csv('E:/iris dataset/adultdata.csv',header=None, 
    delimiter='*,*', engine='python')
    print(adult_df.isnull().sum())
```

heres the traceback-

```
        C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:41: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\iris dataset\naive_bayes_adult_dataset.py", line 9, in <module>
    adult_df = pd.read_csv('E:/iris dataset/adultdata.csv',header=None, delimiter='*,*', engine='python')
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 440, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1024, in _make_engine
    self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2089, in __init__
    self.columns, self.num_original_columns = self._infer_columns()
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2455, in _infer_columns
    line = self._buffered_line()
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2530, in _buffered_line
    return self._next_line()
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2635, in _next_line
    orig_line = self._next_iter_line(row_num=self.pos + 1)
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2695, in _next_iter_line
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2229, in _read
    pat = re.compile(sep)
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 233, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 855, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "C:\Users\Sharanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 616, in _parse
    source.tell() - here + len(this))
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter `delimiter` expects either a single character delimiter or if its more than one character it treats it as a RegEx.

Asterisk (`*`) has a special meaning in RegEx - repeat previous character.

In your case `delimiter='*,*'` there is nothing to repeat for the first asterisk.

So try this instead:

```
delimiter='\*,\*'
```

if you really have `*,*` as a delimiter